# social-share-button popup instead of opening new tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, socialshare

I'm using [social-share-button](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button) for my project.

When clicking the buttons, it opens a new tab to share, is there any way to make it as pop up instead of opening to a new tab?

```
<%= social_share_button_tag("my title", :url => "http://this is a test url") %>
```

should be something like [facebook share plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button). Clicking the share button just opens a small pop up window, and after sharing it closes.

or anyone can lead me to a better rails gem to help me with facebook/twitter sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation of this gem you could pass a block of argument in the function you are calling to generate your link like in this example

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@post.title, :name => "galao", :target => "_blank" other =>"other block as you wish") %>
```

No social_share_button is the only one that I know but as it doesn't displays 100% as you like you could try instead implementing a javascript library instead.

you could use any javascript libraries for the popup

have you try https://github.com/sonnyt/prettySocial [demo](http://sonnyt.com/prettySocial/)

[jquery-plugin for social](http://jquery-plugins.net/category/social)

...have you look at ruby-toolbox in case there is one that could fit your needss

Comment: i have tried `<%= social_share_button_tag("my title", :name => "test", :target => "_blank", :url => "http://this is a test url") %>` but this still opens a new tab, what i wanted to do is open a small popup window with the facbebook share page in it

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question at first :(

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this gem shows you can use the following to enable a popup:

`<%= social_share_button_tag(@post.title, :popup => "true")`

However there was a bug.  The fix has been committed to the Github repo, but a new version of the Gem has not been released. Instead of including this in your Gemfile:

`gem 'social-share-button', '~> 0.1.8'`

Use this:

`gem 'social-share-button', github: "huacnlee/social-share-button"`

Run `bundle` and restart your app.  This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to pop-up instead of opening a new tab by adding `:popup => "true"`

like this:

```
<%= social_share_button_tag("my title", :url => "http://this is a test url", :popup => "true") %>
```